# Find endomorphism given a basis and its image.

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand why my procedure is wrong, and why my book solves this problem in a different way. The problem I am struggling with is the following:

> Determine an endomorphism in $\mathbb{R}^2$ $f$ such that $f(2,5)=(1,3)$ and $f(1,3)=(1,-1)$.

Then, my understanding is that, since $B=\{(2,5),(1,3)\}$ and $\bar{B}=\{(1,3),(1,-1)\}$ are both bases of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the matrix:
$$P=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    3 & -1
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

Is the matrix associated with f in the bases $B$ and 
$\bar{B}$, so that $Y=PX$ would be the matricial expression of $f$. Then, if we wanted to know the matrix associated to $f$ in the canonical basis  of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which we could call $B_0$) we would need to write down both basis change matrices. We shall call $Q$ the matrix that translates from $B$ into $B_0$ and $R$ the matrix that translates from $\bar{B}$ into $B_0$. So, if we establish: $$X_0 = QX_{B}$$ $$Y_0 = R Y_{\bar{B}}$$
And we already know that: $$Y_{\bar{B}} = PX_B$$
Then we can apply a little bit of algebra to find out that: $$Y_0 = RPQ^{-1}$$

But my textbook implies that what I called $\bar{B}=\{(1,3),(1,-1)\}$ are two vectors expressed in terms of the canonical base of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and therefore the correct operation is: $$Y_0 = PQ^{-1} X_0$$

Being the only difference that my textbook doesn't mention any necessity of using the change of basis matrix $R$. Where is my understanding flawed? If a linear function $f$, specifically an endomorphism, takes a basis $B$ to a different basis $\bar{B}$, isn't the basis given by the vectors of $\bar{B}$ the matrix associated to the basis $B$ and $\bar{B}$? Or am I just misinterpreting what the images of $B$ are, and they are, in fact, expressed in terms of the canonical basis?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's done: any linear map is fully determined by where it sends a basis. In particular, take any $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and write it as $v = a(2,5) + b(1,3)$ for real $a, b$ (which we can do since $\{(2,5),(1,3)\}$ is a basis). Then $f(v) = af(2,5) + bf(1,3) =a(1,3) + b(1,-1)$. I'm assuming that you want to write it in terms of the standard basis, so we'll do that: if $v = (x,y)$, we first need to compute $a$ and $b$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. This is a simple simultaneous equation:
\begin{align*}
x &= 2a + b\\
y &= 5a + 3b
\end{align*}
Solving these gives $a = 3x - y$ and $b = 2y - 5x$ (no, those numbers aren't coincidences).

Thus, we have \begin{align*}f(x,y) &= (3x-y)(1,3) + (2y-5x)(1,-1) \\&= (y - 2x,14x - 5y).\end{align*}

Comment: I think I see my error, then. Your answer does, indeed, match the one provided by my book. Thank you very much.

Comment: To be specific: your error is right at the start: the matrix that you give is the matrix of $f$ in the bases $B$ and $B_0$, not $B$ and $\overline{B}$: that latter matrix is just the identity.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. Thanks a lot!